# How to make a class behave like an array?

Tags: javascript

I know I could create my own `Number` class by overriding `valueOf`

```
function MyNumber(n)
{
    this.n = n;
}

MyNumber.prototype.valueOf = function() { return this.n; };
```

Then I could do this:

```
var n = new MyNumber(10);

console.log(n + 1); // 11
```

I want to know how I could access each value by index, like this

```
function MyArray(a)
{
    this.a = a;
}

MyArray.prototype.valueOf = function() { return this.a; };

var a = new MyArray([1, 2, 3]);

console.log(a[0])
```

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't overload indexing operator (or any operator) in JavaScript.

You could imitate it by making `MyArray` constructor copy `a[i]` to `this[i]`, but you won't get the magic of `length`.

Comment: Not saying this is a good idea, but you can define getters and setters for a `length` attribute

Comment: @6502: Good point. I still haven't quite gotten to terms with JS attributes.

Answer (score 4):

That's as simple as a `for... in` loop:

```
function MyArray(a)
{
    this.a = a;
    for(var it in a) this[it] = a[it];
}
```

Actually, jQuery does something very much like this which is why you can do something like `$('body')[0]` and get the `body` tag. The jQuery object, when it has received the return of the seletor query, goes through each of those indexes and maps it to `this[i] = <selected node>`. And while Arrays do have a special `length` property, that type of assignment will get you most of the way there.

Comment: Apparently it is costly to access class members, and Chrome and Firefox doesn't seem to keep a cache. (LocalRef vs Normal) http://jsperf.com/loop-of-a-class-member And what if I want to remove elements from the array, I also all indexes "moved"... It doesn't feel like a real array...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by returning a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) from your constructor.

```js
class ArrayLike {
  data = [];

  constructor(...args) {
    this.data.push(...args)

    return new Proxy(this, {
      get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
        const n = +prop;

        // Number access works like array index
        if (!isNaN(n)) {
          return target.data[n];
        }

        // Other access passes through
        return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
      }
    });
  }

  get length() {
    return this.data.length;
  }
}

const notArray = new ArrayLike("a", "b", "c");
console.log(notArray[0])
console.log(notArray[1])
console.log(notArray.length)
```

This class in this example won't have the other array methods.

[The answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65331639/592125) shows a way to extend the native Array, and make negative indices return from the end of the array.