# How to make a getter proxy for all instances of a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, es6-class, es6-proxy

Proxies can be used to define 'general getters' for objects. For example

```
var obj = {'a':3, 'b':4 };
var proxy = new Proxy( obj, {
    get: function(obj, prop){return obj[prop]+10} 
} );
proxy.a //13
```

I have a vector class that extends `Array`:

```
class vec extends Array{
   constructor(...a){
      super(...a)    
   }
   get x(){
      return this[0];
   }
   /* some more functions */
}
```

and I want the index to wrap around like in python. For example if `v`  is a vector I want `v[-1]` to return the last element of `v`. To do this I would need to wrap a proxy around each vector instance (I think) so I could clamp the index. But I don't know how to make a proxy for all instances I only know how it works for a single object. So how would you do this?

Comment: Returning an object from a constructor-function is valid, or you could use a factory-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your class so that it returns a instance of a proxy, and on that proxy you create a get method where you add your custom logic.

```js
class Vec extends Array {
  constructor(...a) {
    super(...a)

    return new Proxy(this, {
      get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
        const n = +prop;

        if (!isNaN(n) && n < 0) {
          return [...target].slice(n)
        }

        return Reflect.get(...arguments);
      }
    })
  }

  get x() {
    return this[0];
  }
}

const v = new Vec(1, 2, 3);
console.log(v[-1])
console.log(v[-2])
console.log(v.x)
```

Comment: I don't think  `[...target].slice(n)` does what the OP wants

Comment: This seems to do what I want and it seems like the right way to do it.. The slice behaviour is not what (I want to take the modulo of the index to clamp it between 0 ... (arr.length-1) ) but that would make a quick modification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I want `v[-1]` to return the last element of `v`.

It seems your `Vector` has a fixed size (e.g. 3 for `.x`, `.y` and `.z`) so you could just define another getter with the name `-1`.

In general, I'd recommend to follow the [*relative indexing* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method) and just implement an `.at()` method, or the [*array `.last`* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-last).

> I don't know how to make a proxy for all instances

You can make your prototype a proxy:

```
vec.prototype = new Proxy(vec.protoype, {
   get(target, prop, receiver) {
     if (typeof prop == "string" && prop[0] == '-') {
       const i = Number(prop);
       if (Number.isInteger(i)) {
         return receiver[receiver.length + i];
       }
     }
     return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver)
   }
});
```

Comment: My class works like an array so it can have any length. The method x() is just a shorthand. I like this answer but Nenad's answer is slightly closer to what I want.

Comment: Is it? You asked for a single proxy for all instances, and that's exactly what my answer does (but Nenad's solution doesn't).

Comment: Well I wasn't really sure what was the best way to implement it I just had a vague idea of what I wanted. Now that I think of it maybe having a single proxy on the prototype gives better performance? I'll think of it some more but right now Nenad's answer stays accepted.

Comment: I would hope it does, but I'd benchmark it to be sure. In any case, even if you create one proxy per instance, I'd recommend passing the same handler object to all of them.